# How can I find a specific digit in the square root of 2 in java?

Tags: java, math

I'm having trouble with my code. I can't give an example of why it's not working because it's a "hidden test", but I can say that the code 100% works for digits from 0-6, as that's what the other test cases were. What the code is supposed to do is return the digit of the index that is inputted into the parameters. For example, if digit is equal to 0, the program would output 1, which is the first digit of sqrt(2). If they inputted 1, it’d be 4, since sqrt(2) is 1.4

```
public static int sqrtTwo(int digit)
{
    if (digit < 0)
    {
        return -1; 
    }
    double two = Math.sqrt(2);
    
    
    /* option 1
    //return (int)((Math.pow(10, digit) * two) - ((int)(Math.pow(10, digit - 1)*two))*10);
    */
    
   //option 2 
   String s = Double.toString(two); 
   s = s.substring(0, 1) + s.substring(2); 
   return (int)(Double.parseDouble(s.substring(digit, digit + 1))); 
}
```

Comment: I’m trying to return the digit of the index given from the parameters. Sorry for not clarifying. For instance, if the inputted integer was 1, the output would be 4 because the first index in sqrt(2) is 4.

Comment: what is the constraint for digits? using `double` and its `pow,sqrt` will always limit your digits... What you need is **different algorithm of computing sqrt digit output directly** (best on integers alone, such algorithms exist IIRC it was also teached in schools in my country decades ago where you compute the `sqrt` by 2 digits at each step sadly I born too late ... try to google also check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512358/calculating-a-sqrt-digit-by-digit) ) otherwise you would need bignums just like the answer here suggest...

Answer (score 5):

Your main problem is double precision. The best way would be to migrate to more precise types, like BigDecimal.

```
public static int sqrtTwo(int digit) {
    if (digit < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    MathContext context = new MathContext(Math.max(digit+1, 1));
    BigDecimal two = BigDecimal.valueOf(2L).sqrt(context); // compute the decimal with any precision matching your digit index

    String s = two.toString();
    s = s.charAt(0) + s.substring(2); // I assume this part removes the separator character
    return Integer.parseInt(s.substring(digit, digit + 1));
}
```

This will return the n digit of the SQRT(2).

Second improvement would be to parse digit to Integer instead of using Double in the middle.